# Read stdin to string in Newlisp

Tags: newlisp

How do you read the entire contents of standard input into a string in Newlisp? (i.e the entire remaining contents after the current read position - this operation is commonly called "slurp file")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
(define (read-all)
  (let (r "" ch "")
      (while (setf ch (read-char))
        (setf r (append r (char ch))))
    r))
```

See also: http://www.newlisp.org/downloads/newlisp_manual.html#read-char